# Spring 3 Controller and Relative Paths

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, controller

Trying to get to grips with Spring MVC Controllers. But having a problem with relative paths

I have a page at:
    `http://localhost:8080/jeeniweb/articles`
on that page there is a menu option :

```
<li><a href="articles/writing_great_code/structure_and_dependencies/">Structure and Dependencies</a></li>`
```

This, in a browser, resolves to:
    `http://localhost:8080/jeeniweb/articles/writing_great_code/structure_and_dependencies/`

When a user clicks on this link  I intercept this request with a controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/articles/{article}/{chapter}")
public String articles(@PathVariable String article, @PathVariable String chapter) 
{
        System.out.println("Articles Page Request");
        System.out.println("article: " + article);
        System.out.println("chapter: " + chapter);

    return "articles/index";
}
```

This method catches the request and the `println` methdods print out the right stuff.
However after the call I want to:
    `http://localhost:8080/jeeniweb/articles`
But in fact the browser goes to:
    `http://localhost:8080/mysite/articles/writing_great_code/structure_and_dependencies/`

How can this be when I am returning `articles/index` from the method?

My Servlet config is:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

As I understand Spring this means the resultant return after the processing above code should be `/WEB-INF/views/articles/index.jsp` which is what I want. That's where the index.jsp page is.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks
Adam

Comment: This is very weired. It should work. Everything is perfect. And if the page is not found then it must throw the 404 error. Can you show the content of your articles/index.jsp page here?

Comment: @Adam: +1 for the well-written question. I still not see anything wrong, but this may be something with the view resolver... could you please show the servlet mapping part too?

Comment: @Adam: a hint: you might want to setup log4j to view what the Spring URL resolver is doing

Answer (score 0):

The controller just knows that it intercepted the correct url, in order to resolve articles/index url, you'd need to have it return a redirect to that url such as:

```
return "redirect:articles/index"
```

Comment: This is not correct. When you use `redirect:` it tries to find the controller with this mapping not the jsp page he wants to display.

Comment: Reread the question, it is correct.  He is wondering why when he returns the String articles/index it is giving him the correct view, but incorrect URL.  Since the last URL he browsed to is the RESTful url of http://localhost:8080/mysite/articles/writing_great_code/structure_and_dependencies/ Spring needs to be told to redirect to articles/index otherwise it will just render the view related the string returned, in this case "articles/index"